# jquery отследить изменение содержимого div

Tags: jquery

Есть class содержимым является цена на товар 
2 040,00
есть кнопка при нажатии на неё цена меняется

мне нужно написать условие
если цена меньше 1000 то вывести 
alert

всё это нужно сделать без перезагрузки страницы

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.b_b_price span').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        var sum = parseInt($(this).text().replace(' ', ''), 10);
        if (sum < 1000) {
            alert('Привет');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: А содержимое блока как меняется? Нельзя разве туда прописать вывод алерта?

Comment: меняется цена при увеличении или уменьшении кол-ва товара, мне нужно написать условие на изменение цены

Comment: Сделайте проверку на событие change, на изменение количества товаров.В этом event берите цену и проверяйте цену
Вот ссылка на .change(https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: @DenisLazarev `change` для `span`? серьезно?

Comment: @Cheg извиняюсь, не увидел span
Значит на клик кнопки проверять цену, а не DOMSubtreeModified использовать

Comment: @DenisLazarev вот это я и имел ввиду в первом комментарии. только не кнопку, а ту функцию, где происходит изменения цены

Comment: Кажется, что вы пытаетесь решить проблему не с того конца. Почему не добавить эту проверку внутрь колбека, который как раз устанавливает новую цену в span? Т.е. по клику на кнопку, вы должны 1. Вычислить новую цену. 2. Добавить цену в span и показать alert.  Если такой возможности нет, то можно по setInterval читать значение из span и так отслуживать изменения, либо посмотреть в сторону MutationObserver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: Именно для искоренения таких вопросов на корню, в ООП было принято решение запретить программисту обращаться к полям классов, и обязать использовать геттеры/сеттеры (getValue()/setValue()), либо свойства (Property), внутри которых, вы смогли бы с лёгкостью вставить вашу проверку изменения значения.